# How to reference a string parm in a sheet = smartsheet.sheets.get(print("%s", SHEET_ID)) call?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, smartsheet-api

I need to pass a variable to my Smartsheet API so that I can run it to write to different Smartsheets.  Right now, when hard code a string (with quotes) "My Smartsheet", the script runs great and my Smartsheet is updated.

```
sheet = smartsheet.sheets.get("My Smartsheet")
```

However, when I use a variable named, `smartfi` I get an error.

**Running script:**

```
pi@cenicapi:~/Documents/tscripts/usage $ ./usage_add.py /home/pi/Documents/usgwrk/CCC-1494.xlsx "My Smartsheet"

*Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "./usage_add.py", line 45, in <module>

    sheet = smartsheet.sheets.get(smartfi)

  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/simple_smartsheet/crud/base.py", line 148, in get
    id_ = self.get_id(name)

  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/simple_smartsheet/crud/base.py", line 125, in get_id
    return self._get_id(name, objects)

  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/simple_smartsheet/crud/base.py", line 91, in _get_id
    f"{self.factory.__qualname__} object with the name {name!r} "

simple_smartsheet.exceptions.SmartsheetObjectNotFound: Sheet object with the name 'CCC-2052' has not been found

pi@cenicapi:~/Documents/tscripts/usage $*
```

How do I pass a variable to the `sheet = smartsheet.sheets.get("My Smartsheet")` so it runs without errors and and my Smartsheet named `"My Smartsheet"` is updated on the web?

Copy/paste of script below for reference:

```
import logging
import csv
import os
import sys
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

excelfi=sys.argv[1]
smartfi=sys.argv[2]

logging.basicConfig(filename='rwsheet.log', level=logging.INFO)

from simple_smartsheet import Smartsheet
from simple_smartsheet.models import Sheet, Column, Row, Cell, ColumnType

data = pd.read_excel(excelfi,header = 0 )
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

cricket_elements = df.values.tolist()

TOKEN = os.getenv("SMARTSHEET_ACCESS_TOKEN")

SHEET_ID = smartfi
smartsheet = Smartsheet(TOKEN)

sheet = smartsheet.sheets.get(smartfi)
print("Smartsheet: ", sheet)

new_rows = []
for element in cricket_elements:

    row = Row(to_bottom=True,
        cells=[
             sheet.make_cell("ccc_key_id", element[11]),
             sheet.make_cell("CCD", element[3]),
             sheet.make_cell("Max_In_Only", element[7]),
             sheet.make_cell("Max_Out_Only", element[10]),
             sheet.make_cell("avg_in_out_max", element[4]),
             sheet.make_cell("MyDate", element[1])
        ])
    new_rows.append(row)

smartsheet.sheets.add_rows(sheet.id, new_rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

Needed to pass parm with quotes (SMH).

Answer (score 0):

On the positive side, if anyone is looking for a working code to create a new row on Smartsheet, this code worked for me.

Here are some prerequisites before running on Linux (Raspberry Pi in my case):

**Need to install the following after Python.**
pip install simple-smartsheet
pip install pandas
pip install xlrd
Log all calls

Parm1=Excel File
Parm2=Smartsheet Name (existing on Smartsheet's Portal)

Good luck!